# Read files from three csv files and computing the following statistics?

Tags: file, csv

Given three files that define the social network:

```
node,type
2001 10,comic
2001 8,comic
2001 9,comic
24-HOUR MAN/EMMANUEL,hero
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,hero
4-D MAN/MERCURIO,hero
8-BALL/,hero
A '00,comic
A '01,comic
A 100,comic
A 101,comic
```

total 19,901 lines

– Contains two columns, node and type. Each row defines a node in the social network. Node is the name of the node and type is either hero or comic.

```
hero,comic
24-HOUR MAN/EMMANUEL,AA2 35
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,AVF 4
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,AVF 5
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,COC 1
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,H2 251
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,H2 252
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,M/PRM 35
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,M/PRM 36
3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN,M/PRM 37
```

96,501 lines

– Contains two columns, hero and comic. Each row defines an edge from a hero node to a comic node in the social network.

```
hero1,hero2
"LITTLE, ABNER","PRINCESS ZANDA"
"LITTLE, ABNER","BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL"
"BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL","PRINCESS ZANDA"
"LITTLE, ABNER","PRINCESS ZANDA"
"LITTLE, ABNER","BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL"
"BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL","PRINCESS ZANDA"
"STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA","FORTUNE, DOMINIC"
"STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA","ERWIN, CLYTEMNESTRA"
```

574,468 lines

– Contains two columns, hero1 and hero2. Each row defines an instance of two heroes appearing in a single comic.

What would the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick read, it looks like you do not need to use any complex data structures or build a whole graph of relationships with data from *all* the csv-s at once.

Let's run through questions:

a) `Number of heroes` - you need to count only entries in `nodes.csv`, that point to a hero.

b) `Number of comics` - as above, just for books. You could do it at the same time as a). If there are duplicates in either heroes or comics, you want to keep them in a `Set`, as that's an easy way of removing duplication.

c) `Mean books per character` - this data is present in `edges.csv`. You want to create a map from `Hero` to `Collection<Comic>`. After that you want to run through all the collection sizes and take the average.

The flow would be similar to:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> heroToComic = new HashMap<>();
for ( /* each csv row line - you need to implement it */ ) {
    Set<String> heroComics = heroToComic.get(heroFromCsvLine);
    if (null == heroComics) {
        // we are adding first comic, so we need to initialize the set first
        heroComics = new HashSet<>();
        heroToComic.put(heroFromCsvLine, heroComics);
    }
    heroComics.add(comicFromCsvLine);
}

// at this stage map is ready
Collection<Set<String>> allComicsPerHero = heroToComic.values();
// now count the average size of collections contained in allComicsPerHero
// cases d & e are similar
```

d) `Mean characters per book` - same as c), just in reverse: `Comic -> Collection<Hero>`.

e) `Mean partners per hero` - you have that data in `hero-network.csv`. You want to keep a map of "who knows who". When you read a record `A knows B`, you need to put two entries in the map: that `A knows B`, and `B knows A` (unless you know your input also has the reverse relations). So again, it's a map `Hero -> Collection<Hero>`. We use a `Collection` here, because a Hero might know more than one Hero, so it cannot be a simple mapping :) You can then count the average again.

Comment: I completed a) and b) but I'm still unsure how to proceed with c),d), and e). How should I proceed with creating a map from 'Hero' to 'Collection<Comic>' while reading from a file.

Comment: See example in c), d & e will be similar. You need to write your own CSV parsing, but it should be easy to connect.

Comment: What is the 'comics' in if(null == comics) supposed to stand for? And what does that conditional statement do exactly?

Comment: Good catch. Meant `heroComics`. Initially the map values are `null`, not an empty set. So we are creating a set that will store the comic names.

Comment: You now need to iterate over all these collections, and take the average of their sizes: `for (Set<String> heroComics : allComicsPerHero) { do_something_with heroComics.size() }`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. My way would be as follows:

- Create separate classes for each CSV file.
- Create ArrayLists of each class and create object for each line in the CSV file and store in respective array list.
- Perform the necessary calculations iterating through the ArrayLists.